# meaning of $value in function formal parameters

Tags: function, arguments, jq, semantics

I'm looking at the JQ "builtin.jq" file, and find

```
def _assign(paths; $value): reduce path(paths) as $p (.; setpath($p; $value));
```

and am trying to figure out the semantics of "$value" as a formal parameter.  It could mean that the parameter is expected to provide only one value, not a list of them.  Or it could be the same as

```
def _assign(paths; vv): vv as $value | reduce path(paths) as $p (.; setpath($p; $value));
```

or maybe it's something else?

I can't find anything in the documentation about this kind of function formal-parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about `def _assign(paths; vv): vv as $value ...`

In essence, a formal parameter, $x, is equivalent to having `x` in the formal parameter list, followed by `x as $x` shortly thereafter.

This is briefly mentioned in the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/):

```
Or use the short-hand:

def addvalue($f): ...;
```

What is not mentioned is that, using this example, `f` can also be used in the body of `addvalue`, though doing so might easily be the source of confusion. For example, what result would you expect the following to produce?

```
echo 1 2 3 | jq -n 'def f($x): x+x; f(input)'
```